# Capturing a certain Part of the view instead of the whole view

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application that has a navigation bar with a share button that captures the view and shares it with facebook, twitter, Imessages etc. In the bottom, I also have a UIStackView which allows me swipe back and forth through my views.

The problem is that when I utilise this code:

```
 @objc func handleShare() {
    print("sharing image")

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        else {return}

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
    present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

It also captures my UIStackView (previous and next button in bottom of the view).

Is there any way I can specify what part of the view I want to be captured?

All the code have been done programmatically, no storyboard coding.

Answer (score 0):

Pass UIView which you want to capture. Make stackView out of the view which you are passing to function.

```
 @objc func handleShare(yourView: UIView) {
print("sharing image")

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourView.frame.size)
view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    else {return}

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? I`m pretty new to Swift.

Comment: This line creates a bitmap image of a size UIView which you mentioned in this line UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourView.frame.size).